# Adding arrows to a div jQuery plugin issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

I just want to add 4 arrows to a div:

[image]

I got it to work:
http://jsfiddle.net/ctNDr/

But when i try to make a jquery plugin, it bugs:
http://jsfiddle.net/DY3EJ/

This is the output:

```
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-top.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="height: 26px; width: 20px; top: 50px; left: 480480px; position: absolute; display: none;">
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-right.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="position: absolute; display: none;">
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-bottom.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="left: 480480px; position: absolute; display: none;">
<img class="arrows" src="arrow-left.png" alt="Arrow-Top" style="height: 20px; width: 26px; top: 50250px; left: 480px; position: absolute; display: none;">
```

Any idea?

Comment: I think you musy work with a relative position or try offset() instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several issues going on, but I was able to get it to work finally.  I removed the `this.each()` function, as it wasn't serving a purpose.  Also your top, right, bottom, left calculations needed to be wrapped in parens. For visual purposes, in the jsFiddle, I made class `.arrows { background-color: red; }` since I didn't have any images to deal with.

**Things to note:**

1. `options.MouseOver` is never used.
2. `options.Fade` and `options.FadeSpeed` are based off the first `.AddArrow()` call due to how you are handling the `.hover()` in the plugin.
3. You may want to consider adding [`.stop(true,true)`](http://api.jquery.com/stop/) before your fadeIn/fadeOut call on hover to eliminate animation queuing.

---

***[Click here to view jsFiddle demo:](http://jsfiddle.net/DotNetScott/X2dPV/)***

```
(function( $ ){

    $.fn.AddArrow = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            ArrowHeight: '32',
            ArrowWidth: '32',
            ArrowPath: 'images/arrow.png',
            Orientation: 'Top',
            Fade: true,
            FadeSpeed: 300,
            MouseOver: true            
        };

        var o = $.extend(defaults, options);
        var pos = this.position();
        var width = this.width();
        var height = this.height();

        switch (o.Orientation) {
            case "Top":
                this.append($('<img>', { 
                    src: o.ArrowPath, 
                    alt: "Arrow-Top",
                    class: "arrows",
                    style: "height: "+o.ArrowHeight+"px; width: "+o.ArrowWidth+"px; top: "+pos.top+"px; left: "+((width / 2) + pos.left)+"px; position: absolute; display: none;"
                }));
                break;
            case "Right":
                this.append($('<img>', { 
                    src: o.ArrowPath, 
                    alt: "Arrow-Right",
                    class: "arrows",
                    style: "height: "+o.ArrowHeight+"px; width: "+o.ArrowWidth+"px; top: "+(pos.top + (height / 2))+"px; left: "+(width + (pos.left - o.ArrowWidth))+"px; position: absolute; display: none;"
            }));
                break;
            case "Bottom":
                this.append($('<img>', { 
                    src: o.ArrowPath, 
                    alt: "Arrow-Bottom",
                    class: "arrows",
                    style: "height: "+o.ArrowHeight+"px; width: "+o.ArrowWidth+"px; top: "+(pos.top + (height - o.ArrowHeight))+"px; left: "+((width / 2) + pos.left)+"px; position: absolute; display: none;"
                }));
                break;
            case "Left":
                this.append($('<img>', { 
                    src: o.ArrowPath, 
                    alt: "Arrow-Left",
                    class: "arrows",
                    style: "height: "+o.ArrowHeight+"px; width: "+o.ArrowWidth+"px; top: "+(pos.top + (height / 2))+"px; left: "+pos.left+"px; position: absolute; display: none;"
                }));
                break;
        }

        if(o.Fade) {         
            this.hover(function() {
                $(".arrows").fadeIn(o.FadeSpeed);
            }, function() {
                $(".arrows").fadeOut(o.FadeSpeed);
            });
        }

    }

})( jQuery );
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [plugin authoring guide](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring). You need to set the name of the plugin like this, `$.fn.yourplugin`

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.myPlugin = function() {

    // there's no need to do $(this) because
    // "this" is already a jquery object

    // $(this) would be the same as $($('#element'));

    this.fadeIn('normal', function(){

      // the this keyword is a DOM element

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

Comment: Ok thanks. But it "worked" otherwise also.
I changed it, but there is the same output.

Comment: Take a look at this, i made some modifications. Basically your calculations were getting converted into strings. http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/DY3EJ/6/